# connecting lines between web elements

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a web page with Bootstrap 5 and a specific design, I've been trying for several days to generate this part but I haven't found anything. I can think of placing a div to generate the horizontal line.

Is it possible to create something like this image?

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bd-example">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/?text=Image cap" alt="Image cap [100%x180]" style="height: 180px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20286%20180%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1879f97305a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1879f97305a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2299.12312316894531%22%20y%3D%2296.6%22%3EImage%20cap%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
      data-holder-rendered="true">
      
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its actually extremely difficult to do and it will not look very nice or be very maintainable, though the effect can be done somewhat easily by using an image for the background which is the cards/lines, in a relative positioned div, then apply the text over the top with absolute positioning and restraints/scaling etc calc() css, then use media queries to switch out for different device sizes

Comment: A positioned pseudo element that contains a `‾‾‾‾‾|_` shaped background image added to each should basically already do the job, if you make the first `‾‾‾‾‾` part of it long enough. Place into a container with hidden overflow perhaps, to not make the  one from the first element to go too far out the left side.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in that snippet attempting to do what you're asking for. This also isn't really a Bootstrap question, and it certainly isn't a PHP question. Please tag your Bootstrap version.